# Remove Space Character from Lucene Standard Analyzer

Tags: java, lucene, analyzer

`StandardAnalyzer` consider space-character as a token, I want `StandardAnalyzer` to not to make tokens using space-character as a token. So how can I override the tokenizer of `StandardAnalyzer`. If NOT the please suggest any other `Analyzer` with example that does not use the space-character as a token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I replace `StandardAnalyzer` with `KeywordAnalyzer`, so this will be use for indexing and searching ... Then in search method I add these lines

```
parser.setDefaultOperator(Operator.AND);
if(searchWord.contains(" ")){
    searchWord= searchWordreplace(" ", "?");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code can helpy ou :

```
Analyzer ana = new StandardAnalyzer(LUCENE_30, Collections.emptySet());
```

Note that, the answer is version-dependent. For Lucene 4.0, use:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40, CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET);
```

**Edit :**

Constructs a StandardTokenizer filtered by a StandardFilter, a org.apache.lucene.analysis.LowerCaseFilter and a org.apache.lucene.analysis.StopFilter.

```
@Override
public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
   StandardTokenizer tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer(matchVersion, reader);
    tokenStream.setMaxTokenLength(maxTokenLength);
    TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(tokenStream);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    result = new StopFilter(enableStopPositionIncrements, result, stopSet);
    return result;
}

private static final class  SavedStreams {
        StandardTokenizer tokenStream;
        TokenStream filteredTokenStream;
}
```

Comment: I am using Lucene 4.3 -> `Version.LUCENE_43`

Comment: And Well the constructor you use in above example is to just set empty list of the `stopWords`. But I want to set the list of tokens  ...

Comment: I don't want to override the `Analyzer`, can you share sample code that just override the token of the `Analyzer`. I will be very thankful to you. :)

Comment: So what's the point in the updated answer ... are you trying to add new token list to the analyzer or what? Sorry I can't get the point. Can you please elaborate ( better with a good example ).